# How to get filltered value from the table using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help. I need the table value as per index after filtration using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

> index.html:

```
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth" style="width:120px; text-align:left;">Name :</span>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="search.shipping_name">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addProductViewData();"  id="addProfileData" value="Import"/>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th> Product Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr dir-paginate="pro in orderDataList | filter:search |itemsPerPage:5  track by $index">
<td>{{$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{pro.shipping_name}}</td>
<td>{{pro.product_name}}</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

In the above code you can see I have one search field and one button above of the table. Here I need suppose user typed one name and filtered value display inside the table. When user will click on that button all filtered data will fetch in JSON format inside controller page. Please help me.

Comment: what issue you are facing???

Comment: Use [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) inside your controller

Comment: @ParthTrivedi : I need to fetch only filltered data from `orderDataList`.

Comment: try by putting `| filter:search` in last of `$index`

Comment: Is there any other way..?